# Angular how to pass array of string to a header parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a custom http interceptor. I want to pass array of string values to a headername. In my webapi , i am getting as comma separated string and not as array. How to get it as array?

Interceptor code:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'providers': ['test1', 'test2']
        }
    });
```

I tried the below solution:
var providers = Request.Headers["providers"];

```
        if (providers.Equals(StringValues.Empty))
            return BadRequest();

        providers.ToString().Split(',');
```

Thanks

Comment: A comma-separated string is how headers with multiple values are *supposed* to be serialised. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Comment: I was going to say something along those lines... It's easy enough to convert them back though

Comment: you can convert string with explode ',' to array.

Comment: Thank you. i have just converted to string and use Split method to get it as array. Thought if there is any other better solution.

Answer (score 0):

var providers = Request.Headers["providers"];

```
        if (providers.Equals(StringValues.Empty))
            return BadRequest();

        var results = providers.ToString().Split(',');
```